# Query in nested objects

Tags: neo4j, cypher

have follow graph

```
CREATE (s1:SOME {id:'s1'} )  
CREATE (s2:SOME {id:'s2'} )
CREATE (a11:ANOTHER {id:'a11', tags:["tag1", "tag2"] } )
CREATE (a12:ANOTHER {id:'a12', tags:["tag2", "tag3"] } )

CREATE (a21:ANOTHER {id:'a21', tags:["tag3", "tag4"] } )
CREATE (a22:ANOTHER {id:'a22', tags:["tag4", "tag5"] } )

CREATE (s1)-[:CONTAINS ]->(a11),
(s1)-[:CONTAINS ]->(a12),
(s2)-[:CONTAINS ]->(a21),
(s2)-[:CONTAINS ]->(a22)
```

and populate records it with follow query:

```
match (s:SOME)
    with s 
    OPTIONAL MATCH  (a:ANOTHER)-[r:CONTAINS]-(s)
    WITH s, COLLECT(DISTINCT a) AS aa

return s.id, aa
```

now I want to add some restrictions on ANOTHER.tags field:

```
match (s:SOME)
    with s 
    OPTIONAL MATCH  (a:ANOTHER)-[r:CONTAINS]-(s)
    where 'tag2' in a.tags
    WITH s, COLLECT(DISTINCT a) AS aa

return s.id, aa
```

result:

```
╒══════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"s.id"│"aa"                                                                  │
╞══════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"s2"  │[]                                                                    │
├──────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"s1"  │[{"id":"a11","tags":["tag1","tag2"]},{"id":"a12","tags":["tag2","tag3"│
│      │]}]                                                                   │
└──────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

But I want to skip s2 record at all, since it not  contains required tag

another thing - what If I want to check multiple  tags ? like ["tag1", "tag2"] (should respond with empty  data in this case ) can I use something like intersection?

Comment: Does the following snippet work for you? `WITH aa WHERE size(aa) > 0` or `WITH DISTINCT a WHERE a IS NOT NULL`, alternatively have a look at the filter function [https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/list/#functions-filter].

Answer (score 0):

You just have to switch from `OPTIONAL MATCH` to `MATCH` only and it should skip null values.

We can also shorten the query by using only a single `MATCH` instead of two:

```
match (s:SOME)<-[r:CONTAINS]-(s)
where 'tag2' in a.tags
WITH s, COLLECT(DISTINCT a) AS aa

return s.id, aa
```